# iPhone 4 Bluetooth Compatability

Tags: iphone, bluetooth, compatibility

I have a problem with the connection between my iPhone 4 and the bluetooth system in my car.

Frequently it will not connect to my car and frequently the connection breaks down during dialling and calls.

When this happens the call is usually still active on the handset and I fumble to establish if the call is still active. Needless to say this is extremely dangerous and frustrating while driving and could easily result in a serious accident.

I contacted Apple Support who informed me that the phone does not have "full blown bluetooth" and "has restrictive compatibility". I was also informed that this fact was stated on the technical spec, but I have not seen it.

Had I been aware of this I would not have purchased the phone.

Is there a way to enhance the connectivity of the bluetooth?

Comment: What is is that you want us to answer? Please edit your question to clarify.

Comment: What is the bluetooth system in the car? is it built in or a small bluetooth device?